# What is correct way to annotate abstract classes inheriting each other using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

I am new with JPA, so maybe someone can explain me how to correctly annotate abstract classes using JPA?
I have an abstract class with generated id field:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

and an abstract class with name which extends AbstractClass:

```
public abstract class AbstractNameClass extends AbstractClass {
    private String shortName;

    @Column(name = "shortName", nullable = false)
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
}
```

I have two types of classes, one extends AbstractClass and other classes extends AbstractNameClass:

```
@Entity
public class Model extends AbstractNameClass {
    // this class should inherit id (from AbstractClass) and shortName (from AbstractNameClass)
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle extends AbstractClass {
    // this class should inherit only id
}
```

If I add @MappedSuperclass annotation on AbstractClass, then I can create and save objects which are extending AbstractClass, but how to annotate AbstractNameClass? I tried to add @Entity annotation, but I got "No identifier specified for entity" error, also I tried to add @MappedSuperclass annotation and also got the same error.
So my question would be - how to correctly annotate abstract classes using JPA, without creating AbstractClass and AbstractNameClass tables (in my db I want to have only Model and Vehicle tables)?

Comment: I think it should be possible to annotate both your abstract classes with `@MappedSuperClass`

Comment: Just tried to annotate both abstract classes with @MappedSuperClass annotation - got the  same error - No identifier specified for entity...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I created 4 classes like you did, annotated **both** superclasses with `@MappedSuperClass` and both subclasses with `@Entity`, created 2 tables in a test-db for the subclasses. My spring application starts fine. And there are no errors. *Have you recompiled your code correctly before running*?